# Update server_name in nginx.conf programmatically

Tags: linux, nginx

I have a trading bot built with flask+gunicorn+nginx deployed on AWS EC2 which runs for 8 hours a day. Everytime I start the instance, the public IP changes which I need to update the `server_name` in nginx.conf.
Is there a way to update this daily with the help of a script or service? My conf file looks like this :

```
server{
                listen 80;
                server_name "public ip I need to change everyday";

                location / {
                            .
                            .}
        }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The `server_name` is optional, do you need to specify it at all?

Comment: Well, almost every guide on deploying flask on EC2 made sure to add the server_name equal to public IP in nginx.conf. Infact, today the bot did not respond to POST requests until I updated the server_name with new IP.

Comment: So, do you have more than one `server` block in this configuration? Use `nginx -T` to view the entire configuration that Nginx is using.

Comment: In 'http' block, I have only one server block which I have set manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Nginx configuration has only one `server` block, make that block the default block. It will capture all requests regardless of the server IP. Therefore, you don't need to specify an IP for the `server_name` directive.

```
server {
    listen       80  default_server;
    server_name  _;
    
    # Please put other settings below.
    #...
}
```

For more information, visit the [Server names](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) document.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I had to also comment out server block in "default" located in etc/nginx/sites-enabled